# Nginx non www redirect to www doesnt seem to work

Tags: redirect, nginx, digital-ocean, http-status-code-301, no-www

I have the following configuration in sites-available/default

I have added the server block to redirect my non www requests to www, as mentioned in the digital ocean [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04). But when I requests the page from the browser, www traffic seem to redirect to non www. But doing a curl -I request from the terminal results in 200 OK for both www and non www. Why is this?

```
 # HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    # HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
    server {
        # Enable HTTP/2
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.example.com;
            ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
        #include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot



    }
```

Curl requests:

```
curl -I https://example.com

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
    Date: Mon, 15 Jan 2018 09:14:10 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 23690
    Connection: keep-alive
    X-Powered-By: Express
    ETag: W/"5c8a-deTNNXHp2f1a8yOhbxbzVmtCHo4"
    Vary: Accept-Encoding



 curl -I https://www.example.com

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
    Date: Mon, 15 Jan 2018 09:15:07 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 23690
    Connection: keep-alive
    X-Powered-By: Express
    ETag: W/"5c8a-deTNNXHp2f1a8yOhbxbzVmtCHo4"
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: Your new `server` block only handles `http` traffic. You only have one `server` block to handle `https` traffic - so it handles **all** `https` traffic.

Comment: @RichardSmith, But I am already redirecting http traffic to https. The server block which you mentioned is actually for www.example.com. But in the browser, my requests to www.example.com also redirects to example.com. Curl requests returns 200 OK in both www and non www casees though.

Comment: `http://example.com`, `http://www.example.com`, `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com` are four different URLs. Each are handled by a different server block except the last two which are both handled by the last server block (despite the `server_name` setting, because it handles **all** https traffic).